# AsyncTask slows down app performance

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I use AsyncTask in my test app to save a lot of records in database:

```
public class Test extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {

private Context mContext;

public Test(Context context) {
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {
}

@Override
protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
    JobsDAO jobsDAO = new JobsDAO(mContext);
    for(int i=0; i<1700; i++) {
        jobsDAO.saveJob("aaaa", "54854874", "sdsdds", 3, "ssdfdsf", "fdfdsf", "dfsfds", "sdfdsf");
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
}
```

}

But when I execute it is slowing my app. Is it normal? Can AsyncTask slow down an app?

Comment: Obvious your data is more than 1500. So it will be slow...

Answer (score -1):

Firstly, you're trying to save 1700 records in one go. That will take a couple of seconds (more than 5 sec approx). Async tasks are designed to execute tasks that last to 4 seconds at the max. What you can do is, you can divide the records in 2 or 3 parts and insert one single part using one AsyncTask. For example, if you have 1700 records, insert around 600 records with one single AsyncTask and when that AsyncTask finishes, start another one to insert the next 600 records. You can start another AsyncTask from the previous one's onPostUpdate() method in the AsyncTask class.

Secondly, in order to save so many records and maintain the system performance, you should use a transaction. There are a couple of methods in the SQLiteDatabase class that will be needed to perform the transaction.

1. To start the transaction, we need beginTransaction() method.
2. To end the transaction, we need endTransaction() method.
3. If you want to commit the transaction, use setTransactionSuccessful() method. This method will commit your changes to the SQLiteDatabase.

You can also use the SQLite transactions to delete multiple records in the SQLiteDatabase.

For more information on the above, see the following link:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html#beginTransaction%28%29